# Access dotnetnuke site

Tags: dotnetnuke

A very nooby question here, but I do need to ask...

I have been passed a dotnetnuke site, created around 2010, all I have access to is the FTP for the hosting space, so I can see all the files. What I need is to find where the site keeps it's admin panel, so I can manage the pages. From what I have seen online, I need to go to mydomain/dotnetnuke, but there is no such subdir on my host, I suppose the old version I am running probably had a different convention.

What are the older defaults for DNN, from around 2010-2011 (community edition)?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the login screen by putting ?ctl=login on the end of the url to the website. You will need the admin account info though to login.

The database will have the username and password, but the password will be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks, I have a long list of credentials from the customer, one of them should work I hope. I'll give it a try tomorrow and update

Comment: It definitely worked, and I've figured the bug on the site out already, thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad you got in